# Model returning null property values MVC C#

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, model

I've got a model like this:

```
public class ProdListModel
{

        public string Col1 { get; set; }
        public string Col2 { get; set; }

}
```

And my code pulls from the db and is supposed to loop through the values and add them to some var lists:

```
var prodind = new List<string>();
var prodtyp = new List<string>();

var productlookup = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdListModel>("select OPIS_Price_Import.ProductIndicator, OPIS_Price_Import.ProductType from OPIS_Price_Import INNER JOIN OPISCodes ON OPIS_Price_Import.ProductIndicator = OPISCodes.productgroup where OPIS_Price_Import.City = @cn and OPIS_Price_Import.ActualProduct = @ap", new SqlParameter("@cn", item.CityName), new SqlParameter("@ap", thing)).ToList();

foreach (var proditems in productlookup) {
    prodind.Add(proditems.Col1);
    prodtyp.Add(proditems.Col2);
}
```

Running the query on the db by itself returns a list of values so I know the data is in there, it's just not populating the model for some reason. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Microsoft says**,
>
> ***Database.SqlQuery Method*** Creates a raw SQL query that will return
>   elements of the given generic type. ***The type can be any type that has
>   properties that match the names of the columns returned from the
>   query***, or can be a simple primitive type.

You must make a small changes can be synchronize model properties with sql columns or use alias in a query

```
public class ProdListModel
{
   public string ProductIndicator { get; set; }
   public string ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

OR

```
      //Sql alias , ProductIndicator AS Col1, ProductType AS Col2
      var productlookup = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdListModel>("select OPIS_Price_Import.ProductIndicator AS Col1, OPIS_Price_Import.ProductType AS Col2 from OPIS_Price_Import INNER JOIN OPISCodes ON OPIS_Price_Import.ProductIndicator = OPISCodes.productgroup where OPIS_Price_Import.City = @cn and OPIS_Price_Import.ActualProduct = @ap", new SqlParameter("@cn", item.CityName), new SqlParameter("@ap", thing)).ToList();
```

[Database.SqlQuery Method Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-5.0.0)